# apache, DNS, access name based virtual host on LAN without typing the IP and server name at the "hosts" file of every computer

Tags: php, apache, dns, centos6, httpd.conf

Hello I have installed a minimal centos 6 web server on a VM with only httpd,mysql, php, ftp,DNS, and some other needed components, everything seems to be working fine, my problem is apache's name based virtual host or DNS?, 
I can access my testwebsite.com on the host machine and other computers connected to the LAN but I need to type the IP address and serverName on the "hosts" file on every computer before they can access it, how do I access my testwebsite.com through LAN without typing additionals on the "hosts" files, please help, thanks in advance

Comment: You don't. DNS exists for a reason.

Comment: is there any workaround how to access the testwebsite.com without typing anything in the "hosts" file, because in an office environment someone with laptop will just connect to the wifi and they need to type the IP and servername in the "host" file first before they can access the testwebsite.com, thanks

Comment: Yes, there is a workaround: ***Put it in DNS***.

Comment: I just followed this tut on setting up dns
[link](http://www.krizna.com/centos/how-to-install-dns-server-in-centos-6/) 
everything works well, I even remove at /etc/hosts the ip and servername, I can still ping using the DNS testwebsite.com, curl testwebsite.com and returns the page index.php I specified in httpd apache vhost, dig, reverse lookup works well, but when I access it in my host computer and other connected devices on the LAN it does not seem to resolve domain name to ip

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can possibly think of achieving this is by changing settings with in the local router(s).

EDIT:
You will have to look at the manual for the particular router you are working with.
Firstly try to login to the router settings page using your browser and looking for the appropriate settings.

If that doesnt work I would probably try to root the router itself and modify the /etc/hosts file

Comment: thanks for the reply, what will I need to configure on the router